# The Opentip hide() not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, opentip

I use the latest version of [Opentip](http://www.opentip.org/) and JQuery-1.9.1

there's a comments area in my page, and each comment has a snapshot of user's img. I want it shows a popup when the mouse moves into the snapshot area. The tip can popup when the mouse entered, but hide() which is called when the mouse leave does not work at all. The tip div popups at the same position again when the mouse entered again. pleae help me, Thanks.

Code pieces:

1. bind mouseenter & mouseleave event while all the comments loaded

```
function refreshTip(className, tipContent) {
    $("." + className).each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).mouseenter(function () {
            showTip(element)
        }).mouseleave(function () {
                var opentips_list = $(element).data("opentips");
               for (var i = 0; i < opentips_list.length; i++) {
                    opentips_list[i].hide();
               }
            });
    });
}
```

1. the code for the showTip func

```
    function showTip(object) {
        var tem = new Opentip(object, {
            fixed: true,
            tipJoint: "left",
            target: object
        });
        tem.setContent("What a day!");
        tem.show();
    }
```

Comment: Removed your swear word for you, there are plenty of young coders on here, there's no need for it!

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < Opentip.tips; i ++) { Opentip.tips[i].hide(); }

Comment: I am so sorry about saying that word. @Mark Walters

Comment: Already tried, and it does not work either @Sora

Comment: cpuld u make a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 3):

Opentip uses the classes in its CSS-file to hide the tooltips.
Make sure you include it in the page aswell.

```
<link href="path/to/opentip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

[From the installation documentation](http://www.opentip.org/installation.html)